# What is the large-n limit of a distribution of the following sample statistic:

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

What is the large-n limit of a distribution of the following sample statistic:$$\displaystyle\frac{\sum^{n}X_{i}}{\,\sqrt{\,\sum^{n}X_{i}^{2}\,}\,}$$ when sampling the Cauchy(0,1) distribution? Monte Carlo simulation indicates that convergence to this limit is quite fast, and that the resulting (symmetric) PDF has very sharp cusps at -1 and +1, but of course does not yield an analytic expression for this PDF - would anyone be able to find it? The following graph indicates how the positive half of the PDF looks like: [image: This is how the positive half of the PDF looks like]

Comment: Does this really converge?  Somehow I'd imagine as $n \to \infty$ you will get extremely large magnitude values frequently enough, the sign of the last one would dominate, so that the sequence would oscillate between near $+1$ and near $-1$.  I.e. for any $n$ the distribution is bimodal but the sequence does not converge with probability $1$.  Just my guess...

Comment: It seems to me that this article could help:
https://www.jstor.org/stable/25050634?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents
"Some Remarks on the Paper 'Sums of Independent Squared Cauchy Variables Grow Quadratically: Applications' by F. Eicker" , Arup Bose
Sankhyā: The Indian Journal of Statistics, Series A (1961-2002)
Vol. 49, No. 1 (Feb., 1987), pp. 138-140

Comment: Now asked and answered at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334131/large-n-limit-of-the-distribution-of-the-normalized-sum-of-cauchy-random-variabl.